# Position element relative to viewport angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular6

In my project I want to position my element from where it is clicked. Right now a modal pops open and pushes the conent down. When this content is closed the next modal gets pulled up again, because it's position is relative. What I optimally want to achieve is for all modals to stay where they are clicked, the top position pulling the other modals down.

I get the top position of the element correctly, but when I use the .css I get `ERROR TypeError: this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.css is not a function`. Is there a way to fix this code or to set the top position relative to the viewport.

```
public toggle() {
            this._active = !this._active;
            if (this._active) {
                const top = this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.css({top: top});
            }
            this.clickEvent.emit((this._active) ? this._question : null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is better version to scroll

```
scroll(): void {
    ...
    const top = this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    window.scrollTo({top: top, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
    ....
}
```

However if you want to just set the y position then you can use

```
this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.offsetTop = top;
```

or

```
this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.style.top = top;
```

Comment: I just want to set the Y position of my element. When im trying to set the offset or top style, I get the same error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'offsetTop' of object '[object HTMLDivElement]'

Comment: Please check again with `this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.style.top = top;`  or `this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.top = top` both should work since `top` is write property.

Comment: They dont give TypeError but don't work. The top isn't set using both methods, even when hardcoding this.singleQuestion.nativeElement.style.top = 10;

Comment: If you are not getting any error and its not working then most probably you are targeting the wrong element. Just print the element `console.log(this.singleQuestion.nativeElement)` and mousehover or click on the printed value. It will take you to actual element whose `top` property is being set.